# What does "vana" mean?

Tags: terminology, spiral-knights

In Spiral Knights, someone just bailed out of my party because he couldn't "make it to vana".  I also heard someone in the arcade say "guess we're back to vana running for today".

What's vana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, they're referring to [Lord Vanaduke](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Lord_Vanaduke), who is a boss down in the Firestorm Citadel down in tier 3.

The party member who bailed probably didn't want to spend his energy without making to a boss.

The others were probably lamenting that they had to work their way to vana instead of being able to catch a ride with a party that was almost there already.